# Accessing route object from VueRouter instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm working on a small service which will work with current route's query parameters.

Unfortunately, it seems like VueRouter has no `route` parameter, so I'm unable to access information I need in service.

```js
import router from "../router";

class QueryParametersService {
    constructor() {
        this.router = router;
    }

    getAll() {
        // Unfortunately, `route` does not exist there
        // but for you, to get the idea, I want to achieve something like this
        return this.router.route.query;
    }
}
```

Of course, router is properly instantiated and works well. Is there any way to access current route from within VueRouter instance? Or is there any way to access the current route from external service? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bad, I haven't read the whole documentation of [VueRouter's API](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-currentroute).

Current route is stored in `router.currentRoute`.

Unfortunately, it's probably a magic method, that's why it not visible when you console.log the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Use this.$route.params.varName

this.$route would be available if vue-router is loaded.

Comment: I'm afraid it will not be available as it's not a vue component (not a Vue scope).

Comment: Have you initialized vue-router?const app = new Vue({ router }).$mount('#app')

Comment: I found it, see my answer above if you're interested. Thanks for the time anyway.